# Deserialise a Json object containing a Json String

Tags: parsing, json

I have a problem where I am unable to de-serialise a Json string to an object in cases where the object already has a Json string in it.

Ex:

```
Class A { 

int a;

String jsonRpresenationOfSomeObject;

// other stuff
}
```

I am unable to de-serialise an object of the above Class A. I get an exception for the field "`jsonRpresenationOfSomeObject`"

Custom de-serialiser is not an option for my use case. Am looking for something generic.
Also found no luck with the Gson library.
Would appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no issue in serializing and deserializing in JSON for the above mentioned scenario of yours.
I have tried and found that the JSON is able to deserialize your class properly.
i think their might be problem with Access-Specifier of your class.

If you still face the problem, then prvide us the sample source.

Comment: Thanks..I was using this class to persist in a h2 db and retreive it back..looks like H2 was swallowing up the "\" characters and hence it was unable to parse that...now I escaped "\" with "\\" and it works fine..